# Java Reflection: the fast way to retrieve value from property

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to use the fastest way to retrieve value from a property.

Should I use:

```
public Object getValue(Object obj, Field field) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return field.get(obj);
}
```

or should I use:

```
public Object getValue(Object obj, Field field) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder methodName = new StringBuilder();
    methodName.append("get");
    methodName.append(field.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
    methodName.append(field.getName().substring(1, field.getName().length()));
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.getName().equals(methodName.toString())) {
            return method.invoke(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

or should I use:

```
public Object getValue(Object obj, Field field) throws Throwable {
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        StringBuilder methodName = new StringBuilder();
        methodName.append("get");
        methodName.append(field.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
        methodName.append(field.getName().substring(1, field.getName().length()));
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().equals(methodName.toString())) {
                MethodHandle mh = lookup.findVirtual(obj.getClass(), methodName.toString(), MethodType.methodType(field.getType()));

                return mh.invoke(obj);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the problem is that you are mixing 2 concepts basically incompatible. If you need high performance, you don't use reflection. You use a well defined api. Reflection is usually less performant from 1-3 magnitude order (any good java book tell that: https://www.amazon.fr/Effective-Java-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0134685997/ref=dp_ob_title_bk)

Comment: @spi I indeed with you. Reflection is not the fastest way to retrieve values. But, unfortunately, I can't change this. I must use reflection. But among all the possibilities, I would like to know what is the best one. Thanks for you reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different levels in there:

- A field access is a field access. A **method** that access the field will ... access the field, too. Just with much more overhead.
- You have to maintain your code over time.

The first point suggests that a "straight forward" field access should always be faster (especially given the fact that this method is pretty short - and the JIT is much better at inlining *short* methods). Leading to the second point: simply ask yourself which of the three methods is the easiest to read and understand.

The key thing is that **reflection** calls are expensive. The *method handle* concept is intended to improve that cost (by avoiding the **checks** that a method call using reflection is undergoing *each* time). So if you are really interested in finding the "optimal" code, then the answer *might* be framed around a solution that computes a method handle *once*, to then be re-used for subsequent calls. There is absolutely no point in instantiating a method handle just to make a single call. Nothing to be gained from that - method handles are "cheaper" than ordinary reflection only when you repeatedly use the method handle to make calls.

Of course, the *real* answer is: you step back, you learn how to correctly [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) java code, and then you do a bit of measuring within *your* context, environment - your data, your code. To then draw your final conclusion. And I also agree with the comment given by `spi` - if performance is crucial to you, then *reflection* is (more or less) a **no go**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 then

1. If you want use run reflection then you should go thought LambdaMetaFactory which gives approx equal performance as of direct method call
   [[faster-alternatives-to-javas-reflection]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557829/faster-alternatives-to-javas-reflection)
2. If you want to make code configurable and but configuration doesn’t change at run time. Then one should go with AnnotationProcessor processor to generate code. It makes perfect combination of configuration, performance, maintenance & ease of use.

[[annotation processing]](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101) [[annotation Processing with maven]](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-se-annotation-processing-api/annotation-processor-generate-code/)

Comment: Nice answer, too. Especially linking to that other answer is pretty helpful. You might want to also include a link for your second point, though.

Comment: The link @GhostCat told is a good idea. I would appreciate it.