# How to invoke constructor using LambdaMetaFactory?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, invokedynamic

I want to try and avoid reflection for invoking a constructor and am trying to follow the LamdaMetaFactory approach taken in this post - [Faster alternatives to Java's reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557829/faster-alternatives-to-javas-reflection#19563000)

My class that I want to construct looks like:

```
interface DBBroker {}

public class NativeBroker implements DBBroker {
    public NativeBroker(BrokerPool brokerPool, final Configuration configuration) {
    }
}
```

Using `LambaMetaFactory` I am trying to construct a `BiFunction<BrokerPool, Configuration, DBBroker>` to replace a direct call to the constructor.

My code so far looks like:

```
Class<? extends DBBroker> clazz =
    (Class<? extends DBBroker>) Class.forName("org.exist.storage.NativeBroker");

MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
MethodHandle mh =
    lookup.findConstructor(clazz, MethodType.methodType(void.class, new Class[] {BrokerPool.class, Configuration.class}));

BiFunction<BrokerPool, Configuration, DBBroker> constructor 
    (BiFunction<BrokerPool, Configuration, DBBroker>)
        LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
                    lookup, "apply", MethodType.methodType(BiFunction.class),
                    mh.type(), mh, mh.type()).getTarget().invokeExact();

final DBBroker broker = constructor.apply(database, conf);
```

Unfortunately this returns the error -

> AbstractMethodError: Method
>   org/exist/storage/BrokerFactory$$Lambda$55.apply(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>   is abstract.

I have tried modifying the various types passed to `LambdaMetafactory.metafactory` but I can't quite seem to get this right, and the Javadoc is certainly not easily understood.

Can someone advise please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mistake you made is in the SAM type you used. The erased type of the `apply` method has to be used for that, so that would be

```
methodType(Object.class, Object.class, Object.class)
```

But you could also use `mh.type().generic()` which returns the same thing:

```
BiFunction<BrokerPool, Configuration, DBBroker> constructor =
(BiFunction<BrokerPool, Configuration, DBBroker>)
    LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
                lookup, "apply", methodType(BiFunction.class),
                mh.type().generic(), mh, mh.type()).getTarget().invokeExact();
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Usually, the classes generated by `LambdaMetafactory` are more efficient than the proxies provided by `MethodHandleProxies`, so it’s not a question of whether you need the `LambdaMetafactory`…

Comment: @Holger Huh yeah, I just wondered about the implementation myself and looked it up. It just uses `Proxy.newInstance` internally :/ I still think it's simpler, but since the goal is performance I'll remove that part.

Comment: @JornVernee `mh.type().generic()` is what I wanted to post before your edit! +1

Comment: For most cases, `erase()` is closer to the intention as `generic()`.

Comment: @JornVernee Now wondering how to do this when the number of args to the constructor is not known until runtime. e.g. my construct function, is supplied with: Class<?>[] paramClasses and Object[] paramValues.

Comment: @adamretter Afaik there is no way to find the constructor method handle if you don't know the exact type, although you could use [`unreflectConstructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#unreflectConstructor-java.lang.reflect.Constructor-) to convert a `Constructor<...>` object to a method handle. But if you're only calling it once and then discarding it, you might as well call [`newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) directly.

Comment: @adamretter Deriving the constructor type from the `paramClasses` would work as long as they match the constructors parameter types exactly (and are not sub types). But you still wouldn't know the interface to use as a wrapper. I guess you could just use the method handle directly.

Comment: Thanks, that was naive conclusion too - that the Interface type could not be derived statically.